# Uploading an already uploaded file to S3 server using paperclip in rails without downloading that file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to find out ways to upload "an already uploaded file" to S3 server without downloading that file from S3 server using paperclip.

The straight forward way is downloading that file from S3 to local system and re-upload it to the S3 using paperclip, but, I'm trying to avoid downloading the file from S3.

Please help me, if we can upload that file directly by using the S3 URL.

Thanks in Advance.

- Nivas

Comment: What do you need this for? Moving to another "directory" ?

Comment: @Zabba : No, I want to have a duplicate copy of the same existing file in the S3 server. In order to have this, I don't want to download the existing file and re-upload it. Instead, I'm looking for the ways, through which we can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way:

```
require "open-uri"

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :picture

  def picture_from_url(url)
    self.picture = open(url)
  end
end
```

Then simply :

```
user.picture_from_url "http://media-cache-ec5.pinterest.com/upload/262827328223677179_oN7ufeP3_f.jpg"
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Can you please elaborate this by using paperclip file upload plugin ? Will this approach fetch the values for the attributes like file_name, file_size, file_type etc...

Comment: @user1509711 Yes this will Try out and let me know if you face any issues. I am using the same code in my project.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working. Can you please tell me whether it will download the file from remote URL to the local system temporarily and re-upload it to the server or will it directly upload from the remote URL ?

Comment: Once you deploy your application on server. It will directly fetch image from url and save on your server. No need to upload manually.